# Ordering and unordering a vector

Tags: r, sorting

I have an algorithm that takes data, sorts it, analyzes it, and then returns scores for the sorted data.  However, the scores correspond to the sorted data, and I'd really like to return scores that correspond to the unsorted data.  I figured there had to be some default R function that does this, but I've had no luck finding anything.  Here's a MWE, and code I wrote that works but is really slow:

```
orig = rnorm(10)
ord = order(orig)
new = orig[ord]
reprod = sapply(1:length(orig), function(x)new[which(ord==x)] )
all(reprod==orig)
```

Are there any ways to "un-sort" data more efficiently?

Comment: You can't use the original, unsorted data?

Comment: Setting `orig=rnorm(10)` would improve the `M` in `MWE` ;)

Comment: @RichardScriven Sorry if I wasn't clear...  The algorithm analyzes the data and produces scores.  The scores correspond to the sorted data (because the algorithm sorts the data), but I want scores that correspond to the unsorted data.  I'm trying to figure out how to get my output back to the original ordering.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: Good point, I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about just:

```
orig = rnorm(100000)
ord = order(orig)
new = orig[ord]
reprod = rep(0,length(new))
reprod[ord] = new
```

Comment: Yep, I agree.  But, otherwise, it works great!  Thanks Eddie!

Answer (score 0):

One nice thing about the ordering vector (the result of the `order` function) is that if you run `order` on the result it gives you the inverse sorting, in other words it tells you how to unsort.  Here is a quick example of what I think you are trying to do in a simple way

```
> orig <- rnorm(10)
> ord <- order(orig)
> score <- seq_along(orig)
> cbind(orig, score[ order(ord) ])
               orig   
 [1,] -0.2429266384  4
 [2,]  0.6346488818  8
 [3,]  1.2956779160  9
 [4,] -0.5563531517  3
 [5,]  1.3299626650 10
 [6,] -1.6062497717  1
 [7,] -1.1444093167  2
 [8,] -0.0004719915  5
 [9,]  0.2734227278  7
[10,]  0.0357991850  6
```

You could also do something like:

```
new[ order(ord) ]
```

to see that it returns the sorted data to the original order.